# Ionic 3 page transition - material design parent-child

Tags: angular, animation, ionic-framework, material-design, transition

I am developing an ionic 3 application and I would like to implement a page transisiton animation from my list of elements to a detail page of a particular element.
What I mean is exactly the effect shown here, in the material design docs:

https://material.io/design/components/lists.html#behavior

Is there any way you guys can help me achieve this in ionic 3 ?
Please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably can use [this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions/)

Comment: @ghuntheur thanks for replying. Unfortunately this plugin only contains four predefined transitions, and none of them is the one that I need.

Comment: So the only solution is to create this transition I think.

Comment: How do you create a transition like this ?

Comment: With angular animation I suppose